# SlidingMenu: disable the swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-mapview, slidingmenu

I am using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) together with a MapView and would like to disable swipe gesture used to open the menu whenever user has the map fragment as the content fragment. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

on SlidingMenu object do `getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);` when your fragment is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

This should work.